# How to update record from alphanumeric to numeric only?

Tags: sql, oracle

Topic   : Data Cleaning - Checking for outlier - Out of pattern

I'm trying update custID from value 'A123' to '123', '22A4' to '224' I only want to keep integer inside custID, I don't want the custID contain  any non-integer character (A to Z and a to z)

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
custID VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY,
custName VARCHAR2(30)
);
INSERT INTO customer(custID,custName) VALUES ('A123','Angel');
INSERT INTO customer(custID,custName) VALUES ('22A4','Chris');
INSERT INTO customer(custID,custName) VALUES ('2333','Chris');

UPDATE customer
SET custID =            -- I want to change 'A123' to '123', '22A4' to '224'
WHERE         ;
```

Comment: `customer_id = regexp_replace(customer_id, '[a-zA-Z]' , '' , 'g')` BTW: this is postgres syntax. Your syntax may vary (especially the fourth argument)

Answer (score 2):

Use this...

```
UPDATE customer
SET custID = REGEXP_REPLACE(custID, '[^0-9]+', '')
WHERE         ;
```

or try this...

```
UPDATE customer
SET custID = REGEXP_REPLACE(custID, '[^[:digit:]]+', '')
WHERE         ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE customer 
SET custid  = REGEXP_SUBSTR (  custid , '[0-9]*' )
WHERE`

[REGEXP_SUBSTR  Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm)